# Number each nested table inside a master table on a Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

So i have the following issue. In my database I have a table named

```
bp_minutes_app.
```

This table stores records of minutes from committee meetings. Each minute can consist of many files. The database design regarding minutes is the following:

The table bp_minutes_attachments is connected via a foreign key to the bp_minutes_app and holds the following information:

```
description, createdby
```

The table

```
 bp_files
```

is connected via a foreign key to the

```
bp_minutes_app
```

and holds the file along other information. We are interested in taking only the name and id of the file (the latter in order to create a hyperlink to the file, but this is out of scope of the present question).
Final remark. All those tables are linked to the master

```
bp_full
```

table that is joined only to get the id of each specific report.

In my report I want to print on a table all minutes and the accompanying information (file name, description, createdby, submission date), but make a separate entry for each minute. In order to achieve this, I first created a table that uses the following dataset:

```
SELECT bp_minutes_app.id
FROM bp_minutes_app
    INNER JOIN bp_full ON
    bp_minutes_app.bp_full_app_id = bp_full.id
WHERE bp_full.id = $P{id}
```

With this dataset I retrieve each minutes record. In my example, I get two records with ids 39 and 40.
Inside this table I nested another table to retrieve information for each file in each minutes record. The dataset that I used is the following:

```
SELECT bp_minutes_app.submission_date,
    bp_minutes_attachments.createdby,
    bp_minutes_attachments.description,
    bp_files.id,
    bp_files.name
FROM bp_minutes_attachments
    left JOIN bp_minutes_app ON
    bp_minutes_attachments.bp_minutes_app_id = bp_minutes_app.id
    AND bp_minutes_app.id = $P{mid}
    left JOIN bp_full ON
    bp_minutes_app.bp_full_app_id = bp_full.id
    left JOIN bp_files ON
    bp_minutes_attachments.bp_file_id = bp_files.id
WHERE
    bp_full.id = $P{id}
```

The *id* parameter is used again to take the specific report and the *mid* parameter to take a specific minute. On parameter specification mid is declared as follows:

```
mid = $F{id}
```

, where id is the bp_minutes_app.id.

Following this setup I managed to get nested tables for each minute (forgive me for the greek headers):

[image]

What I want to do is number each subtable from 1...n, according to the number of minutes/ subtables. How can I achieve this? I tried to create a suitable variable but it was not met with success. I want to somehow "save" in a parameter / variable the count of bp_minutes_app records and manipulate this number for each nested table header, instead of just numbering each table with the corresponding *id*.

Sorry for the long post but I am new to Jasper and I wanted to be clear about the steps I have taken and what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alot of sql not much jrxml in your post so I start by guessing.

Have you tried something like this in the jrxml:

```
<variable name="counter" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Comment: yes but for whatever reason it doesnt produce the desired result

Comment: What result does it produce?, what result do you like to have?

Comment: I want each sub-table to take numbers "1,2,..." and not the id. It doesnt seem to do anything because after rebuilding the report I stil get the id as a result

Comment: put in the textfield you need to reference the variable not id hence $V{counter}

Comment: It worked. I just had to put the text field on the master table as column header and not in the nested.

Comment: Great, or pass the variable to the nested as a parameter ;), check answer accpeted if you feel that your issue is solved.